# How to check if a file is downloaded using protractor selenium?

Tags: selenium, protractor

This is the path

```
 capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {

            prefs: {
                download: {
                    'prompt_for_download': false,
                    'directory_upgrade': true,
                    'default_directory':  'src/test/javascript/e2e/downloads'
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

I download the file with this,

```
productDashboardPageObject.exportDashboard();
```

It downloads the file, but I am not able to check if it was downloaded. It has only count in name, so I can check if it contains count.

After all is done I will delete files, so only those files will stay after I download.

I did lots of things but could not manage.

Comment: You could try opening the file as outlined in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27031924/1106708).

Comment: You may also apply (with the help of `browser.wait()`) `glob` to the downloads directory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41082777/protractor-test-download-file-without-knowing-filename.

Comment: How can i create multiple directories inside /src/test/javascript/e2e location? the thing is I want to download two different files in two different directories let say download1/ and download2. How can i achieve this? capabilities: { 'browserName': 'chrome', 'chromeOptions': { prefs: { download: { 'prompt_for_download': false, 'directory_upgrade': true, 'default_directory': 'src/test/javascript/e2e/downloads' } } } }

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34115)

Answer (score 1):

First delete any already downloaded files in the download location:

```
 deleteAlreadyDownloadedFiles: function(){
      var filename = global.downloadsPath + '/fileName.extension';
      var fs = require('fs');
      if (fs.existsSync(filename))
      {
        // delete if there is any existing file with same name
        fs.unlinkSync(filename);
      }

    },
```

And perform the download action and *then* verify the file is downloaded or not:

```
 verifyFileDownload: function() {
  var filename = global.downloadsPath + '/fileName.extension';
    browser.driver.wait(function() {
      return fs.existsSync(filename);
    }, 30000).then(function() {
      console.log("Getting the ERROR while downloading file as file is not downloaded.");
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did, in protractor+typescript using Jasmine. If anybody knows better implementation please do share.

```
First, do:

npm install download-file --save
```

Page Object:

```
const downloadsFolder = require('downloads-folder');
const fs = require('fs');

export class TestPage{
...
...   

async verifyFileInDownloadsFolder(fileName: string) {
    await console.log('Getting users download path ' + downloadsFolder());
    const filePath = (downloadsFolder() + '\\' + fileName). replace(/\\/g, '/');
    await console.log('Getting the path ' + filePath);
    await browser.wait(async() => fs.existsSync(filePath), this.DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME_SECONDS * 1000, 'File never appeared!');
    await expect(fs.existsSync(filePath)).toBe(true,
      'Failed to download file: ' +  fileName + ' in user directory' + filePath);
    await console.log('File download was successful');
  }
}
```

Spec:

```
Import {TestPage} from './projectpath.po'

describe('testsuite desc', ()=> { 
    let test: TestPage;
    beforeEach( async()=> {
        test = new TestPage();
    });

    describe('test case name', ()=> {
        it('TC desc', async()=> {
            await test.verifyFileInDownloadsFolder(abc.docx);
        });
    });
});
```